# Unit Testing non returning functions in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

you might remember me or running a kind of a 'Lightroom' panel, using C++ and Qt for GUI.
Today I was reading about implementing a unit testing for my main classes, but my question is, how can I test a function that does not return anything?

for example, I got that function:

```
void ImgProcessing::processMaster(cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& tmp, int brightness, int red, int green, int blue, double contrast){

for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            if(k == 0)  //_R
                tmp.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>((img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] + brightness + red )*(259 * (contrast + 255) / (255 * (259 - contrast))));
            if(k == 1)  //_G
                tmp.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>((img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] + brightness + green )*(259 * (contrast + 255) / (255 * (259 - contrast))));
            if(k == 2)  //_B
                tmp.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>((img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] + brightness + blue )*(259 * (contrast + 255) / (255 * (259 - contrast))));
        }
```

this function just take the obj 'mat img', and modify the 'mat tmp' obj.
than I update the UI for display the modified image, by using another dedicated function in my gui class.

Has someone already encounter something like that?

Comment: This is a normal returning function. It modifies `tmp` and `img`, that is those parameters are used to store returned results.

Comment: what are the pre and post conditions? Thats what you want to test against. Whether the function returns something is secondary. Even for a `void foo();`, either there are post conditions that can be checked, or it cannot be tested in the first place

Comment: For comparison: `void f() { for(;;) { } }` would be a non-returning function, examples from real world are `exit` function or those of `execve` family (which do not return *unless* there's some error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not make a difference if it returns a value the regular way or via an output parameter. The procedure is the same anyway. Run the function and check that the output parameter has the expected value.

This is C code, but it does not make a difference for understanding the concept. Consider these functions:

```
int addOne1(int x) { return x+1; }

void addOne2(int x, int* ret) { *ret = x+1; }
```

These can now be tested in this way:

```
const int x = 3;
int ret1, ret2;

ret1 = addOne1(x);
addOne2(x, &ret2);

assert(ret1 == 4);
assert(ret2 == 4);
```

If the output parameter also is an input parameter, then you of course need to make sure that you know the initial value.

```
void inc(int *x) { (*x)++; }

int x=3;
inc(&x);
assert(x == 4);
```

Technically, modifying a parameter IS considered a side effect. But as long as you are careful it's not a big issue. The difference compared to using a member variable is huge. And if you start modifying globals you will soon make it REALLY hard to test the code.

Comment: Thanks Klutt! I understand that, so in my case, I mostly need to compare images obj, so like, in Qt there's QCOMPARE(x,y) in that case, but will it handle my necessities?
I mean, for my related function, in order to testing it I have to compare my 'mat tmp' obj to another 'mat xxx' obj already modified with some values?

Comment: @AlessandroCerro Going for lunch now. Get back to you later.

Comment: @AlessandroCerro You could compare just the individual members instead: `QCOMPARE(mat.whatever, 7)`.

Comment: Generalising the answer a bit: You can unit test *any* function that produces some observable changes in your system. That could comprise changing global variables, raising a signal, calling other functions (you might need to exchange these to be able to observe appropriately; the exchanged function might then just increment some counter you evaluate at another place).

Comment: @AlessandroCerro I don't know anything about the Qt framework for unit testing. But in principal yes. Create a `Mat` object with the expected values and then compare the result with that.